# How do you append www. to a Django url?

Tags: python, django, nginx

Currently I am using nginx and uWSGI to host my website. I need to append www. to my urls, but I'm not sure what is the best route to take.

Should I be doing this at the nginx level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, nginx is the most efficient way to *prepend* (or append) `www`, though Django provides a settings `PREPEND_WWW` that does the exact same thing when set to `True`.

E.g. in your nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```